# Spring Boot Spark on K8S (Minikube): cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda

Tags: spring-boot, maven, apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

I've seen others have been dealing with this same issue, but since none of the proposed solutions or workarounds worked for me and I've already spent hours on this, I figured I would share my specific case in detail in hope someone could point out what I'm missing.

I wanted to experiment with running a very simple Spark Spring-Boot application on a Minikube k8s cluster. When I run the app locally (using `SparkSession.builder().master("local")`) everything works as expected. However, when I deploy my app to minikube, I manage to get my driver pod to spin up the executor pods when the job is triggered, but then I get this exception on my executor pods:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec.func of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec
```

Here is my spring-boot app. For the sake of simplicity of sharing this, I kept all the logic on the controller:

**WordcountController**

```java
@RestController
public class WordCountController implements Serializable {
    @PostMapping("/wordcount")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String hostIp;
        try {
            hostIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("count.words.in.file")
                .setMaster("k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc:443")
                .setJars(new String[]{"/app/wordcount.jar"})
                .set("spark.driver.host", hostIp)
                .set("spark.driver.port", "8080")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "default")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "spark:3.3.2h.1")
                .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName", "spark")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.dynamicAllocation.deleteGracePeriod", "20")
                .set("spark.cores.max", "4")
                .set("spark.executor.instances", "2");

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .config(conf)
                .getOrCreate();

        byte[] byteArray = file.getBytes();
        String contents = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Dataset<String> text = spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList(contents), Encoders.STRING());

        Dataset<String> wordsDataset = text.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String, String>) line -> {
            List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
                words.add(word);
            }
            return words.iterator();
        }, Encoders.STRING());

        // Count the number of occurrences of each word
        Dataset<Row> wordCounts = wordsDataset.groupBy("value")
                .agg(count("*").as("count"))
                .orderBy(desc("count"));

        // Convert the word count results to a List of Rows
        List<Row> wordCountsList = wordCounts.collectAsList();

        StringBuilder resultStringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        // Build the final string representation
        for (Row row : wordCountsList) {
            resultStringBuffer.append(row.getString(0)).append(": ").append(row.getLong(1)).append("\n");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resultStringBuffer.toString());

    }
```

Here is my maven `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>wordcount</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wordcount</name>
    <description>wordcount</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spark.version>3.3.2</spark.version>
        <scala.version>2.12</scala.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--Spark java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/janino/InternalCompilerException-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-kubernetes_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and here is the **Dockerfile** I'm using to package my spring-boot application before deploying it to minikube:

```
# Use an existing image as the base image
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the compiled JAR file to the image
COPY target/wordcount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/wordcount.jar

RUN useradd -u 185 sparkuser

# Set the entrypoint command to run the JAR file
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "wordcount.jar"]
```

For the `spark.kubernetes.container.image` I built a docker image using the Dockerfile which is shipped with my local Spark bin (spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3 - same Spark version used by my spring-boot app) following [these instructions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images) and loaded it to minikube.

Here are some of the things I tried with no luck so far:

- Share my app's jar with Spark using `setJars(new String[]{"/app/wordcount.jar"})` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser/28367602#28367602) - this absolute file-path is where my app's jar lives on my driver image
- use maven-shade-plugin as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58098501/10185326) to change the way my app's jar distributes its dependencies - this resulted in a `ClassNotFoundException: SparkSession` exception on my driver pod.
- Refactor my controller's code to not use lambda functions (didn't make a difference):

```java
public static class SplitLine implements FlatMapFunction<String, String> {
   @Override
   public Iterator<String> call(String line) throws Exception {
       List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
       for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
           words.add(word);
       }
       return words.iterator();
   }

...

Dataset<String> wordsDataset = text.flatMap(new SplitLine(), Encoders.STRING());
```

Any tips or hints regarding my setup or suggestions on how I can refactor my code to get it to work with the existing setup would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to get around this issue by turning this example into a [maven multi-module project](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module).

This allowed creating a separate jar for the executor code and then letting Spark know about it using spark-config:

```
.setJars(new String[]{"word-count-spark-job.jar"})
```

More on this solution in [this blog-post](https://www.itaydafna.dev/blog/spring-boot-spark-on-minikube/#project-structure).